# Are historical results from Google Distance Matrix API available?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Is it possible to get historical results (i.e., what the time travel time and distance would be at some point in the past) from Google to match results from the Google Distance Matrix API?

I would be willing to pay extra for it.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make the question more specific. 1) In what way would this match results from Distance Matrix API? 2) What kind of TRANSIT_MODE do you need this data for- I assume it's DRIVING in which case the API does not support serving. If you would like to let the API team know you are interested you should create a FR @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188841&template=788013

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it may still be helpful. The distance matrix API allows you to input the departure_time parameter. This would allow you to look at travel distance and time from points in the past all the way since Midnight, Jan 1, 1970 UTC. However, this will only work if travel mode is set to transit. If you need travel mode to be driving, you can only enter a departure time that is the current time or a time in the future. Please check out the distance matrix API document for additional information here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

I hope this helps!